# How should I solve this cipher with pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, encryption, pointer-arithmetic

The question reads:

> Solve the following cipher using Pointer Arithmetic. The given string is GKQTEHIN. Define a pointer and set it to the letter ‘T’ in this string. Traverse the string forward and backward. Add/subtract a single value (key) between 1 and 5 to each letter to solve this cipher and form a meaningful word. Hint: You will be using this as you solve it.

Hopefully this has been done correctly...

```
char given[]="GKQTEHIN";
char *pointer; 
pointer=&given[3];

pointer-=3;
printf("%c", *pointer-4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer+4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer-4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer-4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer+4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer+4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c", *pointer-4);

pointer+=1;
printf("%c\n\n", *pointer+4);
```

The word "COMPILER" is printed.

Comment: _How do I "add/subtract a single value...to each alphabet"?_ -- don't you think you'll get a better answer to this question from your professor or TA?

Comment: Please ask your teacher to double-check the string "GKQTEHIN" -- I think it should be "GSQTYXIV"

Comment: That question is crap, you've already done all the parts that are unambiguous and the given string produces zero "meaningful" words no matter how the ambiguous parts are interpreted.  I am with Adam that the given string is not encoded in this way or just plain wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the input from everyone and will keep trying. I emailed him last night and haven't received an individual response, but he posted a message to our entire class saying "The alphabets I and E will switch positions in the final, decrypted word."

Comment: OH, so I figured out just with pen and paper and messing with the alphabet that the answer is "COMPILER". For each element in the string (from left to right) you subtract 4, add 4, subtract 4, subtract 4, add 4, add 4, subtract 4, and add 4. Whew. Fun. I'm not sure of how to use a loop to do this less tediously, though. Then again, the instructions don't call for that...At least I have something to turn in, I suppose. Thanks for all the words, guys.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I "add/subtract a single value...to each alphabet"?

A computer only understands and works with numbers, since everything is a number (or can be considered a number) in a computer. This means letters are actually numbers internally. `char` in C uses [ASCII encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which makes each letter correspond to a number. So you just add the key to the code representing that `char`. You can use `char` as a number with no problems.

```
char a = 'a';
a++;
printf("%c\n", a); // prints 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some value to come char, use the following. You can do this for a whole string by looping over it.

```
int main()
{
    char ch = 'a';  // or some other character
    int x = 2;  // or some other value
    ch = (ch - 'a' + x) % 26 + 'a';  // make sure you have a value between 'a' and 'z'

    printf("%c\n", ch); // prints 'c'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. But would that really count as pointer arithmetic...?

Comment: Well, I am not really understanding your exercise perfectly. It says: "Traverse the string forward and backward." and then "Add/subtract a single value (key) between 1 and 5 to each letter". So I am not really sure on what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah...I'm having trouble connecting the dots too. Thank you for your input, nonetheless.

Comment: the pointer arithmetic is for pointing to the letters (the traversal).  so pointer+=1 moves right one and pointer-=1 moves left one... just be sure you stay inside the string by comparing to &given and &given +strlen(given)

Comment: So you just have to use the pointer arithmetic to traverse through the string? And then you can add or subtract things from the character?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Just do pointer-=1 until I've gotten to index 0 and then pointer+=1 until I've gotten to the highest index for traversal. But I couldn't tell you whether "add/subtract" means "add AND subtract" or "add OR subtract"...

Comment: I assume the offset amount (starting at 3 probably being normalized to zero there since it will then fit all letters) from the starting point would be the number to add/sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply two concepts here:

**First, `pointer` is a variable that contains the *address* of one of the characters in `given[]`.**

If you add 1 to it, it will point to the next character. If you subtract 1 from it, it will point to the previous character.

But you need to keep it within the boundaries of the array. So `pointer` can never be less than `&given[0]` (or just `given`, which also evaluates to the address of the first element), and you should stop incrementing when it points to the null character (`\0`) at the end of the string. You can do this by creating a loop that increments `pointer` at each iteration, handles the boundary by resetting `pointer` to `given` when it points to the null character, and stops when it hits the `T` again.

**Second, `*pointer` is the character that `pointer` points to.**

You can change the character by adding to or subtracting from `(*pointer)`. For example, you've initialized `pointer` to `&given[3]` (which is the same as `given + 3`), so it points to the letter `T`. So `(*pointer) + 1` would be `U`, and `(*pointer) - 2` would be `R`. If you want to save the new character, you can write

```
*pointer = (*pointer) - 2;
```

or just

```
(*pointer) -= 2;
```

You also need to worry about "falling off the end" of the alphabet. For example, `(*pointer) + 7` would be the character after `Z`, but you probably want it to "wrap around" back to `A`. The simplest way to do this is to subtract 26 if `*pointer > 'Z'` (because there are 26 letters in the alphabet) or to add 26 if `*pointer < 'A'`. You can also use the modulus operator (`%`), but that's more complicated.

---

Putting that all together:

- We know that we'll always be adding a constant value between -5 and 5.
- We'll test each value by adding it to every character in the string and printing the result.

Here's an algorithm that will do that:

1. Create a loop with a variable, say `key`, that runs from -5 to 5.
2. Inside the loop, reset `given` to its initial string.
3. Also inside the loop, create a *second* loop that

   1. initializes `pointer` to `given + 3`,
   2. adds the value of `key` to the character at `*pointer`,
   3. increments `pointer` during each iteration
   4. wraps back to the beginning of the string when `pointer` hits the null character, and
   5. stops when `pointer` gets back to `given + 3` again.

I'll leave it to you to write the code. Feel free to update your question if you get stuck, and remember to add the code you've written!

Good luck!

Comment: but there are characters outside the range of A-Z, on the lower end you may get spaces, tabs, newlines, numbers..., on the upper end you can have punctuation, lower case,...

Comment: Given the level of the assignment, and the fact that the original word contains only capital letters, I'll bet money that the answer is also an all-uppercase word.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically traversing this, looking for a pattern:

```
-5 BFLO CDI
-4 CGMPADEJ
-3 DHNQBEFK
-2 EIORCFGL
-1 FJPSDGHM
+0 GKQTEHIN
+1 HLRUFIJO
+2 IMSVGJKP
+3 JNTWHKLQ
+4 KOUXILMR
+5 LPVYJMNS
```

but the instructions for traversal and key adding are clear as mud so you need to try each way (basically like a word search for an unknown word that spans the puzzle).

Forward and backward could mean all the way forward, then all the way back or forward and back simultaneously.

Adding a constant key (2, 3 or 4) would give you a row, but traversing rows forward and back from any point in a row appears to yield garbage, so that leaves the index (possibly with a constant) as a key variable, so you need to look at patterns like '//', '\', '/\', '/' backward and forward as well as from middle to end and end to middle, where the diagonal lines indicate direction.